# Why is BSDL syntax so wordy?

Tags: vhdl, jtag

Looking at BSDL now, one can be surprised that BSDL doesn't look like XML, for example.

I understand that the first IEEE-1149.1 was released in 1990 and XML 1.0 was released in 1998. Even knowing this, I don't understand why the standard creators made it so wordy.

For example, instead of

```
entity SOME_IC is
  <...>    
  INSTRUCTION_LENGTH 4
  <...>
end SOME_IC
```

or even

```
entity SOME_IC is
  <...>    
  attribute INSTRUCTION_LENGTH = 4;
  <...>
end SOME_IC
```

this attribute must de defined as

```
entity SOME_IC is
  <...>    
  attribute INSTRUCTION_LENGTH of SOME_IC : entiny is 4;
  <...>
end SOME_IC
```

This syntax looks like VHDL, but why? Was there any reason for this use of VHDL?

Comment: My feeling is that VHDL was heavily influenced by ADA, and so this might also be the case with BSDL.

Comment: I think the influence must have the reason. I want to know what is the reason. May be *.bsd was applied to simulators/synthesize with testbenches and main VHDL codes or something else. But I want proof of my assumption.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page on BSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_scan_description_language) is quite clear about the inheritance from VHDL. The proof is left as an exercise for you. ;-)

Comment: The Wikipedia is quite clear that BSDL is subset of VHDL (which I actually have read before type this question), but Wiki doesn't describing the reasons of this choise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BDSL is meant by design to be a subset of VHDL. Per IEEE-Std 1149.1, paragraph B.4:

> BSDL is a subset of VHDL (IEEE Std 1076-1993) and shall be fully
> conformant to the requirements of the VHDL standard.

One of the reasons for this is chip designers can define boundary scan register directly in the top level source for the chip, in a way tools will insert boundary scan features automatically. What ends up being public BSDL definition may be a subset of chip source code.

If I understood the way it has been standardized correctly, BSDL was not in 1149.1-1990, and became a de-facto standard from the industrial tools before being imported in 1149.1-2001. That may explain some of the most cumbersome aspects of the syntax (like the boundary cell defined as a string literal with a custom syntax).

You'll probably get more background context in paper from that time:
Parker, K.P., Oresjo, S. *A language for describing boundary scan devices.* J Electron Test 2, 43–75 (1991). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00134943